# Binary search tree traversal in C

Tags: c, time-complexity, big-o, binary-search-tree

I have this function that traverses a binary search tree and appends nodes to a list if they are between a given lower and upper bound.

```
// n - the current node
// l - a list to accumulate results
static void doTreeSearchBetween(Tree t, Node n, Record lower,
                                Record upper, List l) {
    // empty tree
    if (n == NULL) {
        return;
    } 
    int cmpUpper = t->compare(n->rec, upper);
    int cmpLower = t->compare(n->rec, lower);

    // search left subtree
    doTreeSearchBetween(t, n->left, lower, upper, l);

    // if node if between lower and upper records append to list
    if (cmpLower >= 0 && cmpUpper <= 0) {
        ListAppend(l, n->rec);
    }

    // search right subtree
    doTreeSearchBetween(t, n->right, lower, upper, l);
}
```

I realised the issue with this code is that it traverses the entirety of the list in-order, making it very inefficient and I'm looking for a way that would allow me to visit as few nodes as possible. The logic isn't working out for me, I was wondering if anyone had any ideas? I tried adding a couple if statements for whenever the current node is less than the lower and greater than the upper bound, that didn't work out for me.

An example of the output:

```
Inserting: 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43
Searching between 10 and 20
Search returned: 11 13 17 19
```

Type defs:

```
typedef struct node *Node;
struct node {
    Record rec;
    Node   left;
    Node   right;
};

struct tree {
    Node    root;
    int     (*compare)(Record, Record);
};

struct list {
    Record *items;
    int     numItems;
    int     maxItems;
};


struct record {
    char familyName[MAX_FAMILY_NAME_LENGTH + 1];
    char givenName[MAX_GIVEN_NAME_LENGTH + 1];
};
```

Comment: You should use `cmpLower` to decide to go left or right, without more details on your tree hard to help you more

Comment: where would I add this in?

Comment: Post the definitions of `Tree`, `Node`, `Record` and `List`. I suspect these are typedefs hiding pointers, which is a recipe for failure.

Comment: edited right now

Comment: Interesting definitions: the `struct list` is not a list, it is a dynamic array, and `Record` instances are indeed inconsistent with the example output, but the code is generic enough to be used unchanged for different implementations of these containers.

Comment: The best advantage of a BST comes when it is balanced. There's no indication this tree is balanced. It may 'become balanced' if cleverly transcribed to a file or another tree. Otherwise, a BST degrades to a linked list. IF the data persists in a file and is not subject to a lot of variation, a sorted array could be binary-searched with much less fuss. Since this OP indicates listing a range of values is one use of this data, segments of the sorted array would **already be** the sorted list. Something smells...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rely on the comparisons to determine whether to recurse on the left and/or right branches:

- if the tree node is below the lower bound, its left subtree can be pruned.
- if the tree node is above the upper bound, its right subtree can be pruned.

Assuming it is empty at the root node, the list will be sorted by construction.

```
// n - the current node
// l - a list to accumulate results
static void doTreeSearchBetween(Tree t, Node n, Record lower,
                                Record upper, List l) {
    // empty tree
    if (n == NULL) {
        return;
    } 
    int cmpUpper = t->compare(n->rec, upper);
    int cmpLower = t->compare(n->rec, lower);

    if (cmpLower >= 0) {
       // search left subtree
       doTreeSearchBetween(t, n->left, lower, upper, l);

       // if node if between lower and upper records append to list
       if (cmpUpper <= 0) {
           ListAppend(l, n->rec);
       }
    }
    if (cmpUpper <= 0) {
       // search right subtree
       doTreeSearchBetween(t, n->right, lower, upper, l);
    }
}
```